# Fetch data in format echo in Javascript function Var

Tags: javascript, php, database, codeigniter

I am trying to fetch data from database in format

> ['Wp-orders',     11],

which will echo in javascript. My code is below -

```
<?php
$query = $this->db->query('SELECT *, count(DISTINCT order_id) as total 
                           FROM wp_orders
                           WHERE order_status="processing"
                           GROUP BY webname
                           ORDER BY  webname');

foreach ($query->result_array() as $row) {
    $Cdata[] = "['".$row->webname."', ".$row->total."]";
}        
?>
```

And i want to echo in javascript Function {}

```
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
      //['Wp-orders',     11],
      <?php echo $Cdata; ?>
    ]);
```

I don't know where i am doing wrong.

Comment: how this is related to cakephp??

Comment: Sorry about that .. Fazal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot echo an array. Perhaps you could implode it into a comma seperated string like so:

```
<?php echo implode(',', $Cdata); ?>
```

EDIT

Also, you are using `$query->result_array()` which returns a multidimentional array, but then using object syntax to try and access the fields.

Change your query code to use `$query->result()` instead:

```
foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
    $Cdata[] = "['".$row->webname."', ".$row->total."]";
}
```

Alternately you can keep your query and use array access syntax:

```
foreach ($query->result_array() as $row) {
    $Cdata[] = "['".$row['webname']."', ".$row['total']."]";
}
```

Comment: @user3193372 Updated my answer with the solution

Comment: I have solved the problem - $Cdata[] = "['".$row['webname']."', ".$row['total']."]"; .. In same Time... What the coincidence.. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

**PHP:**

```
$i = 0;
foreach ($query->result() as $row) 
{
   $Cdata[$i]['webname'] = $row->webname;
   $Cdata[$i]['total'] = $row->total;
   $i++;
}
```

**JS:**

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
  ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],

  <?php
     $size = sizeof($Cdata);
     for($i = 0; $i < $Cdata; $i++)
     {
         echo "['".$Cdata[$i]['webname']."', ".$Cdata[$i]['total']."]";
         if($i != $size-1)
         {
             echo ",";
         }
     }
  ?>
]);
```

Comment: Its not getting data $Cdata[] = "['".$row->webname."', ".$row->total."]";

Answer (score 0):

If you work with JS, you need JSON

```
$a = array('sd', 'sds', 1);

echo json_encode($a); // ["sd","sds",1]
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
foreach ($query->result_array() as $row) {
    if($row->webname && $row->total){
         $Cdata[] = array($row->webname=>$row->total);
    }
}



var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
  ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],

  <?php
     echo json_encode($Cdata);
  ?>
]);
```

Comment: Got this - [{"":null},{"":null}]

Comment: make a simple condition before you set `the array`